# Restart QThread with GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I am using QThread to do some calculations in a separate Thread.
The Thread gets started by a button click, witch launches the function `StartMeasurement()`.
The Thread can finish the process by itself (after finished the calculations)
and emits the PyQT Signal finished. Or the thread can be stopped by the User by the `stopBtn` click.

The `terminate()` function is working, but I get a lot of troubles when I try to start the thread again.

Is it recommendable to use the `movetoThread()` approach here?
Or how could I ensure that the thread is stopped correctly to enable a proper restart. (means, starting new!)

```
# starts the measurment in a Thread: StartMeasurement()
    def StartMeasurement(self):            

        self.thread = measure.CMeasurementThread(self.osziObj, self.genObj, self.measSetup)

        self.thread.newSample.connect(self.plotNewSample)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.Done)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.thread.terminate)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.Stop)

        self.thread.start()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a problem. The general practice when working with `QThread` is to connect its `finished()` signal to the `deleteLater()` slot of the objects that have been moved to the separate thread via `moveToThread()`. It's done in order to properly manage the memory when you then destroy your thread because it's assumed that you will first quit the thread and then destroy its instance. ;) This should tell you that stopping a thread has nothing to do with the destruction of those objects UNLESS you have established the connection I've described above.

It is perfectly fine to restart a thread IF you have stopped it properly using `quit()` and `wait()` to actually wait untill the stopping is completed.

However my advice is to not do that unless that extra thread has a huge impact on your application for some reason (highly unlikely with modern machines).

Instead of restarting the thread consider the following options:

- implement a `pause` flag that just makes the thread run without doing anything if it's set to `true` (I've used [this](https://gitlab.com/aleksandaratanasov/qt_qthread_qobject_demo/tree/master) example of mine many times to demonstrate such behaviour (check the `worker.cpp` and the `doWork()` function in particular) - it's in C++ but it can be ported to `PyQt` in no time)
- use `QRunnable` - its designed to run something and then (unless `autoDelete` is set to `true`) return to the thread pool. It's really nice if you have tasks that occur every once in a while and you don't need a constatly running separate thread. If you want to use signals and slots (to get the result of the calculation done inside the `QRunnable::run()` you will have to first inherit from `QObject` and then from `QRunnable`
- Use futures (check the [Qt Concurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) module)

I suggest that you first read the [Example use cases](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#example-use-cases) for the various threading technologies Qt provides.